# Change input name by another input value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use Vue.js 2 for my thesis and I need to set up each input value by writing that **specific** value into another input.

I tried some `v-model` hacks but I couldn't achieve my desired result.
Here is what I have so far:

The code below is a snippet that is generated in *for* loop:

```html
<div class="uk-flex uk-flex-between uk-margin-small-bottom" style="align-items: center">
    <input  v-model="box-'+this.index+'-input-'+this.counter+'"
            class="uk-input uk-margin-small-right uk-width-expand"
            type="text"
            :name="box-'+this.index+'-input-'+this.counter+'"
            placeholder="Text"
            aria-label="">
    <a uk-toggle="target: #modal-'+this.index+'-input-'+this.counter+'"
       class="uk-icon-link"
       uk-icon="icon: pencil; ratio: 1.2"
       style="color: #39f"></a>
</div>
<div id="modal-'+this.index+'-input-'+this.counter+'" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <input v-model="box-'+this.index+'-input-'+this.counter+'"
               class="uk-input uk-margin-small-right uk-width-expand"
               type="text"
               aria-label="">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve:
When the code above is generated for the first time, it has `box-0-input-1` id. I want to change the first input's name by taking value from second input (inside the modal) so that when I submit all the inputs, I can have:

> 'name' => 'John'

instead of

> 'box-0-input-1' => 'John'

I got everything else worked, this is the only barrier.

Comment: Could you please add a [mre]? The code you've given isn't much to go on, and is mostly extraneous.

Comment: How do you get this ```'name' => 'John'```? btw, It's hard to see what will be the output on your code above. If you can clarify the question or making an workaround, maybe your question can be answered in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

v-model must be a variable to hold the value of the input.  If the v-model of the second input binds its value to some variable, you can then use that variable to set the `name` attribute of a different input, which is what I believe you're asking for.

First input

```html
<input
  v-model="inputVal"
  type="text"
  :name="firstInputName"
  placeholder="Text"
/>
```

Second input

```html
<input
  v-model="firstInputName"
  type="text"
/>
```

Script code:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      firstInputName: '',
      inputVal: ''
    }
  }
}
```